# MySQL delete rows in a table using Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I am using Python3 and MySQL. I have a string value in date and time format (dateS).

```
  import datetime
  dateS = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  # print(dateS)                 # 2018-08-27 00:30:00
```

I need to delete rows in table "bts_l3_single_value_data" checking with the condition where start_time  is equal to mentioned datetime.

```
  sql = """DELETE FROM bts_l3_single_value_data WHERE start_time = dateS"""
```

When I execute this I'm getting an error as " Error:  (1054, "Unknown column 'dateS' in 'where clause'") " and when I print the sql statement it gives as;

```
 DELETE FROM bts_l3_single_value_data WHERE start_time = dateS
```

without converting the dateS string to datetime format.

Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `dateS` as a string, if you want to put parameter there better use `f strings`

```
sql = f"""DELETE FROM bts_l3_single_value_data WHERE start_time = {dateS}"""
```

But it's better to use [sql variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) for more secured.

Answer (score 0):

use `.format` for inducing value like this in sql query. Below is an example for that

```
sql = """
         DELETE FROM from bts_l3_single_value_data where start_time ='{}'
       """.format(dateS)
```